# Where is $node->view set?

Tags: views, nodes, hooks

[views_preprocess_node()](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_preprocess_node/7) contains the following code.

```
  if (!empty($vars['node']->view) && !empty($vars['node']->view->name)) {
    $vars['view'] = $vars['node']->view;
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__view__' . $vars['node']->view->name;
    if (!empty($vars['node']->view->current_display)) {
      $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'node__view__' . $vars['node']->view->name . '__' . $vars['node']->view->current_display;

      // If a node is being rendered in a view, and the view does not have a path,
      // prevent drupal from accidentally setting the $page variable:
      if ($vars['page'] && $vars['view_mode'] == 'full' && !$vars['view']->display_handler->has_path()) {
        $vars['page'] = FALSE;
      }
    }
  }
```

The part to which I am interested is the line that initializes a variable using the value of `$vars['node']->view`. I looked at the code executed from the Views module for a node, but I was able to find where `$node->view` is initialized.

Which of the node hooks (e.g. `hook_node_view()`, `hook_node_load()`, `hook_node_presave()`) would get a valid value for `$node->view`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick grep of the views module points to the [`views_plugin_row_node_view`](http://api.drupal.org/api/views/modules!node!views_plugin_row_node_view.inc/class/views_plugin_row_node_view/7) class, whose `render()` function contains the following lines:

```
$node->view = $this->view;
$build = node_view($node, $this->options['view_mode']);

return drupal_render($build);
```

So when a node is rendered using the node row plugin, the view is attached to the node object immediately prior to it being passed through `node_view()`, which is why you see it in the theme preprocess functions.

To actually answer the question (which I missed before), `hook_node_view()` would get a valid view object, while the others you mentioned wouldn't (I don't think).